# How to get multiple columns from one column, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, pivot

I have been looking for the solution for a while, I have the following SQL database:

```
| Date                  | Name          | Value |
|-----------------------|---------------|-------|
|  01-01-2020:12:00     |  sensor01     |   5   |
|  01-01-2020:13:00     |  sensor01     |   15  |
|  01-01-2020:14:00     |  sensor01     |   25  |
|  01-01-2020:12:00     |  sensor02     |   10  |
|  01-01-2020:13:00     |  sensor02     |   20  |
|  01-01-2020:14:00     |  sensor02     |   30  |
```

What I want to do is to actually spread the data from the Name column in multiple columns where the Values are matched under each column. So as follow:

```
| Date                  | Sensor01      | Sensor02  |
|-----------------------|---------------|-----------|
|  01-01-2020:12:00     |  5            |   10      |
|  01-01-2020:13:00     |  15           |   20      |
|  01-01-2020:14:00     |  25           |   30      |
```

I tried several things including: the "PIVOT" function and "when case" but that didn't really help and I am still stuck!
How can I best do that? which functions should be used?

I am still beginner, so any tips / ideas / advice are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want them grouped by the date and hour?

Comment: Yes and thank you very much, your solution worked perfect!
you're the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    date,
    max(case when name = 'sensor01' then value end) sensor01,
    max(case when name = 'sensor02' then value end) sensor02
from mytable
group by date
```