# Oracle Row Into Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am having 2 tables, Customers and Customer Contacts table.

**Ex: Customers**

Column:

```
Id
Customer Name
```

**Contacts Table**

Column

```
id
customer_id
contact_no
```

I need to fetch a record by below format.'

Customer Name, contact_no_1, contact_no_2 .... etc.

I'm using oracle 11g.

Comment: How many rows for 1 customer can exist in the Contacts table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply  Ankit, It's N no. not a static value

Comment: One customer can have N of contact details..

Comment: But is there a maximum value for N; or at least a maximum you can reasonably assume? The number of columns in the result has to be known; if it isn't (because you can't limit N) then this changes from a simple static pivot to a more complicated dynamic pivot.

Comment: Ok, let us assume up to 25 records per customer. Can you help me on this

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot%2boracle?tab=Frequent) out

Comment: Do none [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+%5Bsql%5D+rows+into+columns) help? This question seems to be asked daily. If not, sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of either case expression or PIVOT to achieve the same.

Please refer to below links

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617277/how-to-get-multiple-columns-from-one-column-sql)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868995/pivot-data-on-a-sql-with-query/63869182#63869182)

Comment: None of the links are tagged Oracle

Comment: But still queries are more or less can be used in Oracle. Pivot and case expression in Oracle and SQL server are almost identical.

Comment: Static pivot queries(containing case when->"conditional aggregation" or containing `pivot` clause) are very similar, but need different tecniques for dynamic queries. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot%2boracle?tab=Frequent) out

Comment: I was only referring to Static based on last comment of user `Ok, let us assume up to 25 records per customer. Can you help me on this`

Comment: Each DBMS might have different dialects. Depending on the shared links : Oracle DB has no `STUFF`, `QUOTENAME` functions, no square bracketed formatting for columns, `date` is a reserved keyword if used as a column name, no @ sign prefixed declaration for local variables , no `+` sign concatenation operators, no `AS` keyword for aliasing tables or subqueries ..etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ranking function (rank, dense_rank, row_number) to assign a nominal sequential number to each contact number for each customer:

```
select cus.id as customer_id,
  cus.customer_name,
  con.contact_no,
  row_number() over (partition by cus.id order by con.id) as rn
from customers cus
left join contacts con on con.customer_id = cus.id
```

and then either use that in a pivot:

```
select *
from (
  select cus.id as customer_id,
    cus.customer_name,
    con.contact_no,
    row_number() over (partition by cus.id order by con.id) as rn
  from customers cus
  left join contacts con on con.customer_id = cus.id
)
pivot (max(contact_no) for (rn) in (1 as contact_no_1, 2 as contact_no_2,
  3 as contact_no_3,  4 as contact_no_4, 5 as contact_no_5))
```

or with a manual pivot using aggregation:

```
select customer_id,
  customer_name,
  max(case when rn = 1 then contact_no end) as contact_no_1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then contact_no end) as contact_no_2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then contact_no end) as contact_no_3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then contact_no end) as contact_no_4,
  max(case when rn = 5 then contact_no end) as contact_no_5
from (
  select cus.id as customer_id,
    cus.customer_name,
    con.contact_no,
    row_number() over (partition by cus.id order by con.id) as rn
  from customers cus
  left join contacts con on con.customer_id = cus.id
)
group by customer_id, customer_name
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=753b7cdea49fe58528a3cc0ace11e5d6) with some made-up data.

I've shown handling up to 5 contact numbers; you need to add as many `in()` values or `case` expressions as you need to handle whatever value of *N* you're comfortable limiting the output to. (If you decide you can't set a limit then you'll have to use a dynamic pivot, which is more complicated.)

I've included `customer_id` in case you can have two customer that happen to have the same name. You don't have to include that in the final projection; in the pivot version that means you will need to list all the columns you *do* want to include.